# Returning a value from a UDF. (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, function

Attempting to create the following function keeps giving me 'Not allowed to return a result set from a function' ... Google has shown me no love. Nor has reading the MySQL docs/examples.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    FUNCTION `sparks`.`ChildCheck`(ParentType VARCHAR(2), ParentID VARCHAR(4)) RETURNS INTEGER
    BEGIN
DECLARE ParentString VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE Kids INTEGER;
SET ParentString=CONCAT(ParentType, ':',ParentID);
SET Kids = 0;
SELECT Kids=Kids+1 AS KidCount
FROM (SELECT parent FROM mod_CMS WHERE dept_id=1 AND parent=ParentString
    UNION
    SELECT parent FROM mod_External_Links WHERE dept_id=1 AND parent=ParentString
    UNION
    SELECT parent FROM dept_mods WHERE dept_id=1 AND parent=ParentString) t1;
RETURN (KidCount);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

That doesn't work.

The following DOES work.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `next_april1`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `next_april1`(inDate DATETIME) RETURNS DATE
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE outDate DATE;
  SET outDate = (SELECT CASE
              WHEN MONTH(inDate) < 4 THEN CONCAT(YEAR(inDate), '-04-01')
              ELSE CONCAT(YEAR(inDate) + 1, '-04-01')
              END);
RETURN (outDate);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

The syntax for the working one is:

```
select next_april1(NOW());
```

and it returns

```
'2012-04-01'
```

I'm looking for the first one to work like:

```
select KidCount('C','3')
```

Output:
    4

I must be missing something between the two functions.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation for [Create Procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html):

> Statements that return a result set
>   can be used within a stored procedure
>   but not within a stored function. This
>   prohibition includes SELECT statements
>   that do not have an INTO var_list
>   clause and other statements such as
>   SHOW, EXPLAIN, and CHECK TABLE.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid reply! I've also read what you are saying re: a function can't return a value ... but based on what I've added to my question, I'm already doing something very similar.